# C++ unkown type error

Tags: c++

For some reason my main.cpp isnt recognizing the type Link which is included through a link.h file and defined in link.cpp. Is it possible that the makefile isn't properly linking them, otherwise afaik I should be including link.h in both the link.cpp and main.cpp and both could recognize Link as a class.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <link.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int i = 10;
while(i >= 0) {

    i--;
}    

Link test = new Link();

std::cout << "Hello, World!2\n";
return 42;
}
```

link.h

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Link {
private:
    string * value;
    Link * next;
public:
    Link(Link * nextLink, string * stringValue);
    ~Link();

}
#endif
```

link.cpp

```
#include <link.h>

Link::Link(Link * nextLink, string * stringValue) {

this.next = nextLink;
this.value = stringValue;
}

Link::~Link() {

delete value;
}

Link * Link::getNext() {

return next;
}

string * Link::getString() {

return value;
}

void Link::printAll() {

if (next != NULL) {
    cout << value << "\n" << next->printAll();
} else {
    cout << value << "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: how are you linking them in your makefile?

Comment: Your link class seems to be missing a closing semicolon.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest you try including link.h using double quotes, instead of < and >; using these instructs the compiler to look for the file into system default include first, whereas double quotes will make it look in your current directory, where I assume you've put it.

So, your code would change to, wherever you reference your header:

```
#include "link.h"
```